# How to open a Word document with a path stored in variable?

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have a Word document with template contents where I will use VBA code to replace a textbox in the Word document with my user name to generate a pdf report for each user.

In my Excel VBA code, where I open the Word document, I need the path of the Word document.
If I hard code the Word document path, everything works.
When I store the path in a cell and assign it to a variable, it causes an error 13 type mismatch.

I declared the variable coverLocation as Variant.
I checked that the path is correct.

When I declare the variable as String it gives the error

> "Object Required"

at `Set coverLocation`.

My simplified code to show the error.

```vb
Sub Test()

'Create and assign variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim saveLocation2 As String
Dim userName As Variant
Dim coverLocation As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set userName = ws1.Range("B4")
Set coverLocation = ws1.Range("B2")

MsgBox coverLocation, vbOKOnly 'MsgBox showing correct path location

'Word variables
Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

Set wd = New Word.Application
wd.Visible = True

saveLocation2 = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & userName & "cover.pdf"
    
'Word to PDF code
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(coverLocation) ' "error 13 Type Mismatch" at this line

With doc.Shapes("Text Box Name").TextFrame.TextRange.Find
  .Text = "<<name>>"
  .Replacement.Text = userName
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

doc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=saveLocation2, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Ending
wd.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Either replace this line: `Set coverLocation = ws1.Range("B2")` with this: `coverLocation = ws1.Range("B2").Value`, or replace  `Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(coverLocation)` with `Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(coverLocation.Value)`. Any of those two should work, don't do both! Personally i'd use option #1 and additionally replace `Dim coverLocation As Variant` with `Dim coverLocation As String`. Also, you should replace `Set userName = ws1.Range("B4")` with `userName = ws1.Range("B4").Value`. In that case, replacing `Dim userName As Variant` with `Dim userName As String` is also advisable.

Comment: I just tried both solutions you gave, they both worked, Thank you so much. 
Can I know the concept behind this? to Set or not to Set

Comment: The concept is easy: You set a variable to an Object (eg a Range, a Worksheet, a Workbook, a Collection...) with set. You assign a simple value (a string, a number, a boolean...) to a variable without set. Special case: when you write `userName = ws1.Range("B4")`, you assign the content of the cell as VBA does implicit `userName = ws1.Range("B4").Value` (this is called *default property*). When you use `Set userName = ws1.Range("B4")`, you assign a Range (with all it's properties like color, border, formatting, address...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my comment as answer to make it more readable. The problem is, that in your code `coverLocation` is a `Range` object, not a string, and the same goes for `userName`.

The best way to fix this, is to replace this line:

```vb
Set coverLocation = ws1.Range("B2")`
```

with this:

```vb
coverLocation = ws1.Range("B2").Value
```

and additionally replace
`Dim coverLocation As Variant`
with
`Dim coverLocation As String`

Also, you should replace

```vb
Set userName = ws1.Range("B4")
```

with

```vb
userName = ws1.Range("B4").Value
```

In that case, replacing
`Dim userName As Variant`
with
`Dim userName As String`
is also advisable.

The final code could look like this:

```vb
Sub Test()

'Create and assign variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim saveLocation2 As String
Dim userName As String
Dim coverLocation As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
userName = ws1.Range("B4").Value
coverLocation = ws1.Range("B2").Value

MsgBox coverLocation, vbOKOnly 'MsgBox showing correct path location

'Word variables
Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

Set wd = New Word.Application
wd.Visible = True

saveLocation2 = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & userName & "cover.pdf"
    
'Word to PDF code
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(coverLocation) ' "error 13 Type Mismatch" at this line

With doc.Shapes("Text Box Name").TextFrame.TextRange.Find
  .Text = "<<name>>"
  .Replacement.Text = userName
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

doc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=saveLocation2, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Ending
wd.Quit

End Sub
```